# Can I precompute/pregenerate pseudo-random numbers for numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I don't think I'm the first one to come up with this slightly unorthodox idea, but I can't seem to get google to show my why it is bad, nor how to do it properly.

I have a piece of code that is CPU-bound, and the second most expensive function is `np.randint(...)` which is called for single numbers (one at a time). I don't have hard requirements for "true" randomness between multiple executions of the program. Hence, I thought it could be smart to precompute/cache a whole bunch (~2 million) of random numbers, save these somewhere, and then have numpy feed me those numbers as required instead of running the rng.

Could somebody please enlighten me as to why this is a bad idea, or how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Something along the line of precompute then serialise to a pickle?

Comment: @S3DEV Yes, that was my first thought; then I thought that numpy has `RandomState`, which made me think that there might be one that loads from files. I couldn't find one, so now I am confused about what is the best way, or why this doesn't already exist.

Comment: For single numbers, the python `random` package might be faster.  But `np.random.randint` can certainly generate a large number of values, and is more efficient that way.  But fetching those values one by one from an array is relatively expensive (more so than from a list).  The ideal is not only generate the whole array of random numbers, but to also it as a whole array, rather than iteratively.

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not this is a bad idea really depends on your application (with respect to the randomness). However generating two million random numbers isn't really expensive:

```
numbers = np.random.randint(..., size=2_000_000)
```

This takes about 40 ms on my machine. Loading from file instead can result in even larger execution times (depending on your file system and how busy it is).

So precomputing all the random numbers and then fetching one at a time seems like a decent improvement (indeed, calling `np.random.randint` two million times takes about 500 times as long). For example:

```
numbers = iter(np.random.randint(..., size=2_000_000))
single_number = next(numbers)
```

If you cannot precompute all numbers (perhaps because your boundaries change dynamically) then you can use [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) which should be faster. Then saving the random numbers from one run and reusing them for the next might be a thing.

```
numbers = []
numbers.append(math.randint(...))  # dynamically generate the random numbers

np.save('numbers.npy', numbers)  # eventually save the numbers
```

Then for the next run, to ensure some level of variation, you can shuffle these numbers after loading them:

```
numbers = np.load('numbers.npy')
np.random.shuffle(numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate your numbers, save them to filesystem and load them back. This script could help you?

```py
import pickle
import numpy as np

# Numbers generation
random_numbers = list(np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000))

# Save numbers
with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(random_numbers, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Load numbers
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
  loaded_random_numbers = pickle.load(handle)

# Check equality
print(random_numbers == loaded_random_numbers)
```

Comment: Yes.  Or use `pandas` to handle the pickling.

Comment: Can you not replace your loop with `np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000)`?

Comment: You are right, I will update the answer, thank you for reporting. I put an explicit casting in order to return a standard Python list, if you need a numpy array just remove the casting.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this before and works like a charm for order of millions:

First create an array of random numbers one time:

```
random_arr = np.random.randint(0, size=20000)
```

And every time you need a random number, simply pick one using this:

```
number = np.random.choice(random_arr)
```

It should boost your performance significantly.

Comment: :D so you suggest to generate a lot of random numbers and then generate another random number to choose which of these random numbers to return whenever a number is needed?

Comment: I don't think that is exactly how choice vs. randint works. Not sure of the backend of it(maybe an unlimited randint is harder vs. a limited from a length of array) but it worked in my case. Try it :) It also keeps the randomness more. and you dont need to create a large array btw. you can create a smaller one depending on your application.